# Manually add a literal column to a table loaded from a file

Tags: pgfplotstable

I would like to use `pgfplotstable` to typeset some numbers stored in
a text file.
I have used `\pgfplotstableread` to achieve that and it worked all
right.
Now I want to add a column to the said table that contains literal
entries, or more precisely mathematical entries.
I think I should use something like `create on use` or
`\pgfplotstablecreatecol` but I am a little confused about how to
actually do it.
Do you know how I could transform this

[image]

into this

[image]

The previous picture were obtained with the following code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}\toprule
         & $c_0$     & $c_1$ \\    
$u \times 10^2$ & -3.8682 & 1.5055   \\
$v \times 10^6$ & 2.1272  & -8.3619  \\
$w \times 10^3$ & 1.1862  & -4.6269  \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{It should eventually look like this.}
\end{table}

\begin{table}

\pgfplotstableread{
-3.8682 1.5055
2.1272 -8.3619
1.1862 -4.6269
}\tabledon

  \centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[header=false,
every head row/.style={
before row={%
\toprule}},
every last row/.style={
after row=\bottomrule},
display columns/0/.style={column name={$c_0$}},
display columns/1/.style={column name={$c_1$}},
/pgf/number format/precision=4,
columns
]{\tabledon}
\caption{This is my current attempt.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you load a table from a file, do you know how many rows are there? Where do you get to know what should be in the inserted column - from another file, or are there exactly 3 rows always and you know they should be marked this way?

Comment: I know the number of rows and exactly what should go in every cell of the first column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `create col/set list` style for supplying the list of cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
-3.8682 1.5055
2.1272 -8.3619
1.1862 -4.6269
}\tabledon

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    header=false,
    every head row/.style={
        before row={%
            \toprule
        }
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule
    },
    display columns/0/.style={column name={}},
    display columns/1/.style={column name={$c_0$}},
    display columns/2/.style={column name={$c_1$}},
    /pgf/number format/precision=4,
    create on use/newcol/.style={
        create col/set list={$u \times 10^2$,$v \times 10^6$,$w \times 10^3$}
    },
    columns/newcol/.style={string type},
    columns={newcol,0,1}
]{\tabledon}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I might have to create a new question, but: what if I want to add a column and I don't know how many columns are there to begin with? How can I tell pgfplotstable to use the column? I can't use `columns={}` because I don't know the other columns?