# Pgftables: How to automatically add row headers?

Tags: pgfplotstable

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

Here is the multiplication table in roman numeral. 

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{
  i   ii   iii
  ii  iv   vi 
  iii vi   ix 
}

I would love it to include the column headers:
\begin{quote}
 1 \quad 2 \quad 3 
\end{quote}
and the same row headers. 

But, I have no idea how to achieve this efficiently with \verb|pgfplotstable|.
I do not want the solution to rely on the number being consecutive; 
ideally, it would take a list such as 
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
  \def\ROMANS{I,II,III}
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: The column headers are easy to fix `header=false,display columns/0/.style={column name={I}}`, for the rows it needs some more work.

Comment: I am aware of it, but it is quite tedious if you are to produce, e.g., the multiplication table of numbers up to twenty...

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood your question so that it boils down to have a *key* that takes a list of column names and assigns it to the single columns:

```
\pgfplotstable[display column names={A,B,C}]{...}
```

If so, the following example does this. It defines a key that takes a list of column names. Note, that it contains code that is taken from another tex.sx answer from [@Villemoes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/275/villemoes) and I know to less about tex to say if it is correct or will work in every case. So I cannot give any warranty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

% taken from one comment of Villemoes in
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15263/3061
\def\pgfglobalkeys#1{\begingroup \ifnum\the\globaldefs>0\relax \else \globaldefs=1\fi \pgfkeys{#1}\endgroup}

% define the new key
\pgfplotstableset{display column names/.code={
        \foreach[count=\n from 0] \x in {#1} {
            \pgfglobalkeys{/pgfplots/table/display columns/\n/.estyle={column name=\x}}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, header=false, display column names={A,B,C}]{ %
  i   ii   iii
  ii  iv   vi 
  iii vi   ix 
}

\end{document}
```

The key code of `column names` is straight forward and easy to understand. It will loop over the given list using a foreach loop and sets the columns name. The problem is that the `foreach` body is encapsulated in a group so that any change to a macro, counter or key is local. So after we quit the loop all keys are reset. Therefor I took the `\pgfglobalkeys` from Villemoes. And then it works :).

[image]

Comment: indeed you are missing the row headers. another convenience is the `/.list` handler to repeat key settings. you can find it in the manual.

Comment: @percusse, that was also my first idea, but with the `/.list` handler you do not have the current loop count which you need.

Comment: and indeed i forgot the row header ..., but they are a different story. But it's time to sleep.

Comment: Oh time to dig up old answers then. I did something like that way back...

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69034/manually-add-a-literal-column-to-a-table-loaded-from-a-file